# Jenkins executing docker, cannot find the entrypoint script

Tags: docker, jenkins

So.. Running `docker-compose run test` inside the Jenkins executor, works. Running it from Jenkins UI (Build now, or actual code change that triggers another build), doesn't.

```
16:37:18 Cannot start service test: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:   
\"./script/docker-entrypoint.sh\": stat ./script/docker-entrypoint.sh: 
no such file or directory": unknown
```

I already tried moving the script outside of the `script/` folder into the root directory, tried adding the script manually after `ADD . /app` with `ADD script/entrypoint.sh /app/script/entrypoint.sh` and also tried restarting docker daemons, Jenkins machine, and stuff.

I cannot seem to make my image run from Jenkins. It runs locally with `docker-compose run test`, it works from the terminal in the Jenkins executor using the same command, but it doesn't from the normal pipeline.

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2

RUN mkdir -p /app

# install Ruby dependencies
ADD Gemfile /app
ADD Gemfile.lock /app
RUN cd /app && \
  bundle config github.com ${GITHUB_USERNAME}:${GITHUB_TOKEN} && \
  BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile bundle install

ADD . /app

# rails server, elasticsearch, and webpack ports
EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "./script/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD [ "script/server" ]
```

And here's my entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

exec "$@"
```

And last, but not least, my `test` service in the compose, that I am trying to build/run:

```
test:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        GITHUB_USERNAME: ${GITHUB_USERNAME}
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: ./script/test -n 4
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: test
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

I would appreciate some insight here because I have no idea how to make my image run correctly in Jenkins.

Comment: did you find anything?